# What rights does a "Privileged" account have?

Tags: accounts, permissions

Is it possible for the "privileged" account to change account permissions on any account?  What else can it do?   Are the privileged permissions documented anywhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Accounts with the prefix `eosio.` are system account and have privileged permission, there was an article about it but it no longer exists.